# iCarousel with UIScrollViews

Tags: uiscrollview, icarousel

Does somebody know how to put the uiscrollviews objects in iCarousel?
I mean IBOutlet objects.

so I tried this way:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
UIScrollView *scroll = [UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame...
scroll.contentSize =..
scroll.backgroundColor = ..
return scroll;
}
```

and it works, but i need to put into carousel an array of uiscrollviews(with a lot of buttons), that i made with IBuilder.

Also I made like this:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
UIScrollView *scroll = [scrollArray objectAtIndex:index];
return scroll;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Are the scrollviews in the same nib file as your carousel, or is each in it's own nib? How are you putting the scrollviews into your array - is it an IBoutletCollection?

Comment: I created 3 nib files named scroll1, scroll2, scroll3, then tryed to do like this - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    for (int i = 1; i<4; i++) {
        
   
    NSArray *titleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"scroll1", @"scroll2", @"scroll3", nil]; 
    view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[titleArray objectAtIndex:i+1] owner:self options:nil] objectATIndex:index]]; }return view}     but it doensn't work so? So how will it be correct   to load several different nib files?

Comment: You should be using view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[titleArray objectAtIndex:i] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed, and you always want the first item in the nib file, not the one matching the item index.

Comment: Sorry, Nick, it's not working, i tryed this way:  view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[titleArray objectAtIndex:index] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: but it loads only the one scroll3.xib..

Comment: i need like this: item1 -> scroll1.xib; item2 -> scroll2.xib; item2 -> scroll3.xib and so on.. maybe it is better not to make the xib files, but make an iboutlet collections of scrolls?

Comment: I didn't notice the loop in your viewForItemAtIndex method before. The code doesn't really make any sense as your use of indexes is all muddled - check my answer for the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct approach:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view

    NSString *nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scroll%i", index + 1];
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
    view = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, Nick, but I'm affraid it;s the same like: view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[titleArray objectAtIndex:index+1] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: So just to be clear, you're returning 3 as the numberOfItems, and you have 3 nibs, named scroll1.xib, scroll2.xib and scroll3.xib, each containing a single scrollview, each different, right? I think maybe you should contact me through github and I'll investigate further because the problem as you've described it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Absolutly right, Nick. I"ll try to make it one more time from the begining, If the problem won't go away, I;ll contact  you, thanks!